# How to archive least used data?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, persistence

Environment: JSF2, persistence with Hibernate, MySQL

I have a database that is rappidly filling because of a table with image data. That data is never searched but only directly accessed by id. Problem is that it stays in the database and so enlarges the backups and the runtime memory usage of the database.

I'm thinking that there could possibly be multiple solutions:

- Tell MySQL that the table should not be cached and/or kept in memory.
- Don't use MySQL at all for that table. Just let persistence know that this should be stored on disk directly.
- ???

But I haven't found a way to do either. Please advice.

Thanks,
Milo van der Zee

Answer (score 0):

Storage type depends on storage engine in MySQL. Only tables having MEMORY storage engine are stored in RAM others are stored on disk.

In select queries you can use `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE` to tell MySQL not to cache query data in MySQL query cache.

You can partition the table by defining partitions on table. This will make inserts and selects faster.

You can also create day wise tables like table_name_2012_07_20 and archive tables with old dates and to store data in compress format you can either use Archive storage engine or if you are using MyIsam storage engine then do myisamchk or myisampack to save disk space on the hard drive.

Comment: Thank you. This looks very promising. One question remains. Does partitioning the tables also remove them from the internal MySQL memory? I don't mean the query cache but the fact that MySQL prefers to have everything in memory. I don't want this in memory ever. It is queried sporadicly and I don't want to push valuable data out of memory just for this.